# Netbeans profile Wildfly Selected methods

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss, wildfly, profiler

I want to profile a selected method in a project that runs in a wildfly server.
When the profiler is setup and the method is called the console will give the following exception: 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/profiler/server/ProfilerRuntimeCPUFullInstr`

Steps to reproduce this problem is as following:

- start wildfly server through Netbeans > Services > Servers > start Wildfly
- Profile > Attach to Project
- Setup Attach to Project > select proces (jboss-modules.jar)
- Select Methods to profile
- Select inside Methods to profile "Selected Method"
- add method from own project and apply
- run method, the exception will be thrown and the profiler is disconnected

I'm using Netbeans 8.1 and Wildfly 8.2.

What i've tried so far:

- adding `-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server`
- http://i-proving.com/2011/07/07/how-to-get-visualvm-to-profile-jboss-without-crashing/ but this gave me the following errors:

  `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/profiler/lib/jfluid-server-15.jar: line 1: PK: command not found
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/profiler/lib/jfluid-server-15.jar: line 2:,�*E: command not found
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/profiler/lib/jfluid-server-15.jar: line 3:+�*E���+BBMETA-INF/MANIFEST.MFManifest-Version:: No such file or directory
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/profiler/lib/jfluid-server-15.jar: line 4: Ant-Version:: command not found
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/profiler/lib/jfluid-server-15.jar: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token ('
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/profiler/lib/jfluid-server-15.jar: line 5:Created-By: 1.7.0_45-b18 (Oracle Corporation)`
- I also tried to start wildfly in profile mode but this hangs after: `Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140 (Protocol version: 16)`

Comment: Could you try with a nightly build from Netbeans (and maybe a more up to date version of WildFly) because it was really hard to have the Profiler working with WildFly ?

Comment: Did you try to start WildFly in profile mode instead of attaching yourself ?

Comment: @ehsavoie I tried this, but this wildfly will hang on start. I will try it later on netbeans 8.2.

Comment: @ehsavoie tested on netbeans (nightly) 201706120001 but with the same result

Comment: Ok I have a fix to be merged into NetBeans for this so that it will start WildFly with the correct options. Would you like to test it ? In which case I would upload a build for you

Comment: Could you try https://www.dropbox.com/s/y35nc13go4bbh76/NetBeans-dev-20170613-unknown-revn-full.zip?dl=0 ? You would need to profile from NetBeans thought as i can't control your WildFly options from the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed soon in the nightly builds. Otherwise if you don't want to use the nightly, this is what you'd need to do on your WildFly instance to be able to connect the profiler to it and profile your method.
In standalone.sh you will need to update certain options :

- append jfluid-server.jar to the bootclasspath (or you could change the command line to use **-classpath jboss-modules.jar:jfluid-server.jar org.jboss.modules.Main** instead of **-jar jboss-modules.jar**)
- add the jfluid package to the system.pkgs like this : **jboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager,org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server**
- add the **-Xverify:none** to avoid error messages

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what is and where to do the first bulletpoints.

Comment: line 310/ 323 of standalone.sh **-jar \""$JBOSS_HOME"/jboss-modules.jar\" \ ** to be replaced with **-classpath \""$JBOSS_HOME"/jboss-modules.jar:/home/dev/netbeans/.../jfluid-server.jar\"  org.jboss.modules.Main**

Comment: For the bootclasspath you have to use JAVA_OPTS